# PyPdf2 cant add multiple cropped pages

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I want to add multiple cropped boxes as new pages in a new pdf file. As result of the below code I get new the right amount of pages but here is the problem. The last page overwrite every single page in the PDF file.

Any suggestion?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

output = PdfFileWriter()
input1 = PdfFileReader(open("1.pdf", "rb"))
outputStream = open("output.pdf", "wb")

page = input1.getPage(0)

page.mediaBox.lowerRight = (205+(0*185), 612)
page.mediaBox.upperLeft = (20+(0*185), 752)
output.addPage(page)
output.write(outputStream)

page.mediaBox.lowerRight = (205+(1*185), 612)
page.mediaBox.upperLeft = (20+(1*185), 752)
output.addPage(page)
output.write(outputStream)

page.mediaBox.lowerRight = (205+(2*185), 612)
page.mediaBox.upperLeft = (20+(2*185), 752)
output.addPage(page)
output.write(outputStream)


outputStream.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean the last page and not the first page?

Comment: Yes i try to crop tickets from page like this one https://ibb.co/bxg24p and in final version i get 12 page pdf but all pages ar nr 12 :(

Comment: Could you share your PDF file?

Comment: Try this code in 2.py file with this pdf exaple file i try a lot of modyfication and always i get the output with 3 pages with number 3

http://www.filedropper.com/2_125
http://www.filedropper.com/1_252

Comment: Please, edit your question with the code in `2.py` and I will post the answer after that.

Comment: i edited the code in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `copy` module in order to make copies of the page object. There's an explanation [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other. This module provides generic shallow and deep copy operations (explained below).

So your code should be like this:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from copy import copy

output = PdfFileWriter()
input1 = PdfFileReader(open("1.pdf", "rb"))
outputStream = open("output.pdf", "wb")

page = input1.getPage(0)

x = copy(page)
y = copy(page)
z = copy(page)

x.mediaBox.lowerRight = (205 + (0 * 185), 612)
x.mediaBox.upperLeft = (20 + (0 * 185), 752)
output.addPage(x)

y.mediaBox.lowerRight = (205 + (1 * 185), 612)
y.mediaBox.upperLeft = (20 + (1 * 185), 752)
output.addPage(y)

z.mediaBox.lowerRight = (205 + (2 * 185), 612)
z.mediaBox.upperLeft = (20 + (2 * 185), 752)
output.addPage(z)

output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Comment: In this exaple at the end i hav a file that weight is 3 times oryginal pdf size. Is there a way to make it lighter (get rid off all elements that i just dont want after setting the cropBox)

Comment: On my macOS machine the input file has the same size of the output file: 126 KB.